# SelectToken without double quotes using Json.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I'm trying to get a string value from a JSON string with Json.Net (Newtonsoft.Json) but it's returning the value with double quotes. Is there a correct way to do this without getting double quotes?

```
Dim rawJson as string = "{""meta"":{""status"":201,""msg"":""Created""},""response"":{""id"":1234}}"
Dim result = JObject.Parse(rawJson)
return result.SelectToken("meta.msg").ToString
```

The above code will return "Created" (with double quotes) instead of: Created. A quick and dirty solution is to do .trim(""""c) but this will also trim any escaped double quotes. Such as "status":"\"Created\""

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I run the above code, I get `Created`, as expected, not `"Created"`.  Is that your actual JSON?

Comment: The response is from Tumblr's api from a web request. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json version 4.0. I doubt it's a VB/C# issue but every C# example shows no problems. The exact JSON response from Tumblr is:

{"meta":{"status":201,"msg":"Created"},"response":{"id":1234}}

Comment: Looks like I found the problem. Was using an outdated version. Went ahead and updated it with no problems and now it's working. :)

Comment: Glad you got it working.